debian boots into emergency mode after "a start job is running for"
Since last week my virtual server was running without any problems. There was no change on the server for weeks. Out of nowhere it does not boot anymore.
While booting there is a message "A start job is running for [...]". At first it shows the boot partition and after that the swap partition. enter image description here I did some research and most of the people with this problem had a problem in their fstab..

I already rechecked the file and tried different ways (UUID, devicenames etc). Without any luck.
Maybe someone of you have a idea what it could be? Secound screenshot shows my fstab and also my blkid.
I'm sorry that I can only show you screenshots... the remote console only offers me screenshot and no text copy/paste...enter image description here


You checked fstab and it looks good to me as well. The other main cause of emergency mode is partition corruption. See part 2 of this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1470673/243321 (change the device names as appropriate)
